# Consulta en dos tablas con SQLITE

Tags: sql

Tengo una duda, tengo dos tablas una se llama `Factura` que contiene

```
ID_FACTURA,
ID_CLIENTE, 
TOTAL,
```

Tengo otra tabla se llama `Detalle` contiene las columnas

```
ID_FACTURA,
ID_CLIENTE,
FECHA.
```

Lo que necesito es hacer una consulta en la cual obtenga de la tabla `Factura` el `ID_FACTURA` el `TOTAL` y que obtenga la `FECHA` de la tabla `Detalle` 
tengo este código pero me da error

```
SELECT FACTURA.ID_FACTURA,FACTURA.TOTAL
FROM FACTURA
INNER JOIN DETALLE
ON FACTURA.ID_CLIENTE = DETALLE.ID_CLIENTE
WHERE ID_CLIENTE = 1
```

Comment: ¿Qué error le muestra ?

Comment: No sale la fecha

Comment: Es porque no añadió el campo en el `select` , es decir `SELECT FACTURA.ID_FACTURA,FACTURA.TOTAL,DETALLE.FECHA
FROM FACTURA .... WHERE FACTURA.ID_CLIENTE = 1 `

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la ayuda era algo sencillo no lo había visto, saludos

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta se debería de incluir en este apartado y no en los comentarios para que el resto de usuarios que busquen algo parecido lo vean fácilmente.Considera marcar esto como respuesta correcta para que el resto lo puedan ver fácilmente.

```
SELECT FACTURA.ID_FACTURA,FACTURA.TOTAL,DETALLE.FECHA FROM FACTURA INNER JOIN FACTURA.ID_FACTURA = DETALLE.ID_FACTURA WHERE FACTURA.ID_CLIENTE = 1
```